# Conditional Select from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement :

There is a column **CNT** from a table A .

If the value of **CNT > 0**

I have to choose column  **SERIAL** and **DESCRIPTION**

from table B else **SERIAL** and  **DESCRIPTION**

from table C .

How can I do this in Oracle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT a.cnt, b.serial, b.description
  FROM a INNER JOIN b
    ON a.key = b.key
 WHERE a.cnt > 0
 UNION ALL
SELECT a.cnt, c.serial, c.description
  FROM a INNER JOIN c
    ON a.key = c.key
 WHERE a.cnt <= 0;
```

Hope this helps.